# How to set traceId, span Id in http headers when using OTEL Auto Instrumentation in JAVA service

Tags: java, open-telemetry

How can i fetch trace Id, span id when using OTEL using Auto Instrumentation? I want this use case as if the request fails then the response header will have span id which we will use for debugging the failed request.

I tried using OTEL auto Instrumentation

Comment: There's an [open feature request](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/9846) for this but it hasn't been implemented yet.  If you want to manually add a response header, you can find the relevant info on `Span.current()`.